# Is the sentence "There's nothing to stop you" correct?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

English is not my first language and I want to include this in a blog article. Does the sentence make sense?

> There's nothing to stop you.

p.s. What I am trying to say is that a person has no more excuses, and nothing can stop him from achieving weight loss. "There's nothing to stop you".

Comment: If you're happy to write ***nothing can stop him** [from doing it]* in your actual question text, I can't see why you have a problem with ***There is nothing to stop him***. Is it the use of the infinitive *(**to stop**)*? Or perhaps it's the direct object *(**you**)*, which makes your example syntactically somewhat different to, say, ***There's nothing to eat***.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is grammatically correct.  I think I would interpret it as an elision of a longer sentence like: "There is nothing to stop you [from ...]."    As a native speaker, I would prefer the gerund here: "There is nothing stopping you."  But they are interchangeable in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. How about this: "There's nothing to stop you from achieving your weight loss goal." I think that this is the best sentence for me to use. Is it better then "There's nothing to stop you"?

Comment: @AndrejNaumoski That is good.